# X-mouse Button Control: press and hold LMB for .5 seconds repeatedly while button is down

Tags: xmouse

I've been using XMBC's simulated keys function to simulate a repeated pressing of the left mouse button so long as I press down on mouse button 4.
Now I am looking for a way to do the very same thing, only holding LMB for .5 seconds each time.

So basically, as long as mouse button 4 is pressed, I want the input to be: press LMB, hold for .5 seconds, release, then immediately press again and keep repeating that until I let go of mouse button 4.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The simulated keystrokes menu has tags for press LMB, release LMB and wait. Using these it was easily possible to solve my question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).